# Factory not working inside Controller

Tags: angularjs

I know this is very trivial question but I'm not being able to understand the problem.

```
myApp.factory("States", ['runajax', function(runajax) {
  var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Dakota", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];

  return states;

}]);

myApp.controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope, States) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;

    $scope.states = States;

console.log($scope.states);

});
```

I check the console and it shows undefined.

Comment: probably something to do with whatever `runajax` is and what it does differently than what is shown

Comment: Even without that runjax service its not working. I keep getting undefined

Comment: Code shown works as noted in answer below. Create a demo that reproduces problem as per [mcve]

Comment: Problem was with my angularjs version. I'm using 1.3.15 and found the solution referring to the angular docs.

Comment: @SubrataBanerjee mark as answer if it has helped

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('States', function(){
  var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Dakota", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];
  return states;
})


app.controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope, States) {
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.states = States;
    console.log($scope.states);

});
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, States){
  $scope.data_list_2 = States.data;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
          <p>Main Controller {{states}}</p>
      </div>
      
      <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
          <p>Second {{states}}</p>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my angularjs version and the injection of factory to controller was wrong.

Comment: Please elaborate: what was wrong with your angularjs version? What was wrong with the injection of the factory? Answers are expected to completely answer the question. See [answer].